# Как обрабатывать касания только внутри приложения и не пускать их дальше?

Tags: android, touch, monotouch

Я написал игру в Android Studio и в ней пользователь делает много различного рода касаний, которые иногда приводят к активации HiTouch, случайным скриншотам, может внезапно всплыть клавиатура и т.п. Мне же нужно, чтобы касания кроме как в игре больше нигде не обрабатывались. Как это сделать?

Например, в моем Huawei при удержании двух пальцев на экране срабатывает HiTouch, а игра ставится на паузу, что плохо. Конечно, я могу отключить HiTouch в настройках телефона, но не каждый пользователь будет это делать и скорее снесет игру, чем будет возиться в настройках.

Я решил проблему через костыль - **FLAG_SECURE**, но это не позволяет в принципе снимать экран, хотя и решает мою проблему - с этим флагом касания остаются в приложении:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Есть ли лучший способ решить эту проблему?
Спасибо!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav - здесь вроде об этом.

Comment: @woesss в этом разделе документации почти все относится к API >= 29, моя проблема встречается и на 27-28 API. Хотя для 29 setSystemGestureExclusionRects должен решить проблему